# Diameter of the image of holomorphic $f: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

NOTE THE FOLLOWING QUESTION ATTEMPTS TO PROVE A FALSE STATEMENT.  I LEFT IT UP THOUGH IN ORDER TO HELP ANYONE ELSE MAKING THE SAME MISTAKE AND TO GIVE CREDIT TO THE RESPONDENTS.

Suppose I have a holomorphic function $f: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$.  Why is the diameter $d=sup_{z,w \in \mathbb{D}} |f(z)-f(w)|$ equal to $sup_{z \in \mathbb{D}} |f(z)-f(-z)|$?  If we weren't looking at image, i.e., the $f()$ wasn't there, then this makes sense.  Why is still valid looking at the image?  Note, also is holomorphic required?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is your definition of ${\mathbb D}$? The disc centered at $0$ with radius 1?

Comment: This is clearly false. Take $f(z)=z^2$.

Comment: Any 'even' function will do.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Turn your comment into an answer, one liners are nice!

Comment: oops I screwed up. I asked this question because I was looking at a problem which I needed to make this conclusion in order to answer the problem or so I thought.  I realize now I only needed to assume the diameter was greater than my other $sup$ which of course it is. DOH!

Comment: @TedShifrin please turn your comment into an answer by the end of the day.  Otherwise, I will answer it so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is clearly false. Take $f(z)=z^2$ (or any other nonconstant even function, for that matter).